# how to use python bolt in storm crawler?

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler, apache-storm-topology

I have some image classifiers that have been written in python. A lot of examples are available on the web which describes the way of using python in storm bolt that uses from stdin/stdout. I want to integrate my python image classifier with storm crawler topology. Is it possible or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible, did that a few years ago to integrate an image classifier with Tensorflow into a StormCrawler topology. Can't remember the details and the code stayed with the customers I wrote it for but it was based on [the multilang protocol](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Multilang-protocol.html), don't remember the details unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. if you are using Flux, this is a sample definition of how to use a python bolt in your topology:

```
  - id: "pythonbolt"
    className: "org.apache.storm.flux.wrappers.bolts.FluxShellBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      - ["python", "/absolute/path/to/your/python_file.py"]
      # declare your outputs here:
      - ["output0", "output1", "output2"]
    parallelism: 1
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you emit simple data types (like string, integer, etc.) to your python bolt. not a java data type, or it'll throw errors!
first download **storm.py** form

[here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py)

And this is a sample python bolt:

```
import storm

class SampleBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
    # Initialize this instance
    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        self._conf = conf
        self._context = context

    def process(self, tup):
        # Some processes here, and then emit your outputs.
        storm.emit([output0, output1, output2])

# Start the bolt when it's invoked
SampleBolt().run()
```